# removing iframe will cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single page application which create and remove a number of iframe based on user input. each iframe could contain a jqgrid, a form for input submission with jquery.validate plugin etc...

the main page could access all the iframes to retrieve current operation status and some data to rebuild the main menu.

is safe to just remove the iframes or i need to `.empty()` the body before removing them?

EDIT:

when i say "retrieve current operation status and some data" i actually access the iframe properties using something like this

```
jqueryFrameObject[0].contextWindow.myCoolProperty
```

but never cache the object in the main page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No : jQuery takes care of removing the elements which could lead to memory leaks :

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

If you don't keep other pointers (including hidden ones based for example on closures), you'll be safe. Be careful not to use the native `addEventListener` if you don't want to keep hidden links to your removed elements.

Comment: ok, jquery remove all bound events and data associated in the *current* window, but what about the contextWindow of the iframe? i'd like to think it's just like closing a tab of the browser, but not sure if each iframe is opened in a separated browser thread. am i paranoid?

Comment: Hard to find references about this point of browser implementation but I don't have problems in my application which build and remove thousands of divs and work for days (industrial process supervision).

Comment: if no solution will come in two days i will accept your answer cause you made me think about changing all my iframes with divs. i read that [iframes cause memory leaks with jquery ver 1.5.2](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/adding-jquery-in-iframe-causes-memory-leak-when-that-iframe-is-reloaded) and with plugins like silverlight, so using iframes could be a problem with or without jquery.